# CSS: Change opacity of background-image within the body element selector

Tags: html, css

I have added a background image inside body using css property as:

```
  body{
   background-image: url('background-img.jpg');
  }
```

Now what I want to do is add opacity property to this background image.
Can we do this without using z-index property (ie. by separating div containing background image and contents)?
If it was within a image tag I could have used opacity : value property inside css selector but its not the case.
Any css tricks or solutions will be appreciated!!

Comment: can you post your HTML code

Comment: you can view my code here!! http://mumstudents.org/~985432/

Answer (score 3):

```css
div {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/300x300);
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.5),rgba(255,255,255,.5)), url(http://placehold.it/300x300);
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div><div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `background` gradient with `rgba()` and `url()` property together.

Just like:

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba(244, 67, 54, 0.95),
                            rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.75),
                            rgba(139, 195, 74, 0.75),
                            rgba(255, 87, 34, 0.95)),
                            url("http://placehold.it/200x200");
```

Look at the snippet below:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6),
              rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6),
              rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6),
              rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)),
              url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200");
}
```

```html
<body>This is some text</body>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Try this
**Snippet**

```css
body{
  height:430px;
  width:430px; 
}
body::after {
  content: "";
  background: url("https://www.google.com.pk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```

```html
<body>
 <h1>Hello world </h1>
</body>
```

Hope this helps you
THANKS